# For Bower, set absolute path for directory setting in .bowerrc

Tags: node.js, bower

I am trying to do this in my `.bowerrc` file

```
"directory": "~/bower_components"
```

which I want is to resolve to the current users home folder:

```
/home/me/bower_components
```

but currently it is being resolved to:

```
[currentDirectory]/~/bower_components
```

Is their a way to get it to point to an absolute path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field you need to set in the `.bowerrc` is `cwd` to give your installs an absolute root.

For example, the `.bowerrc` file:

```
{
  'cwd': '/var/www/libraries',
  'directory': 'vendor'
}
```

will result in all your `bower update/install` commands to place packages in `/var/www/libraries/vendor`.

I experimented with using `~` for the `cwd` parameter, and Bower didn't understand it.

The documentation for what Bower expects to find in `.bowerrc` is in [this Google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1APq7oA9tNao1UYWyOm8dKqlRP2blVkROYLZ2fLIjtWc/edit#heading=h.motxgepy7e9s).

Comment: The current latest version 1.6.4 states that the cwd option shouldn't be used in .bowerrc. https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/config.md#cwd